# Django Rest Framework - how to customize serializer field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently working on DRF.

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    content = models.CharField()
    category = models.CharField()
    created = models.CharField()
```

Below, the Response I want to get

```
[
    {
      "id": "1",
      "content": "a",
      "category": "post",
      "created": "2020-01-23"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "content": "b"
    },
]
```

How can I get the response like above just using ONE model.

Comment: convert data from model to dictionary or json

Comment: Use [DRF Serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)

Answer (score 1):

So basically you need to take a look first at https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer.

Hope this example can help you:

**view.py**

```
class PostListView(BaseApiView):
    serializer_class = PostListSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        posts = list(Post.objects.all())
        res = PostListSerializer(posts, many=True)
        return Response(res.data)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PostListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super(PostListSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        if not data.get('category'):
            data.pop('category', None)
            data.pop('created', None)
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [dynamic serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields) and do something like this:

serializers.py

```py
class PostSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['id', 'content', 'category', 'created']
```

views.py

```py
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .serializers import PostSerializer


class PostListView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        post1 = Post.objects.get(id=1)
        post3 = Post.objects.get(id=3)
        post1_serializer = PostSerializer(post1)  # all fields
        post3_serializer = PostSerializer(post3, fields=['id', 'content'])
        data = [post1_serializer.data, post3_serializer.data]
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```